# Mit den Wörtern "Stufe" und "Niveau" über Sprachkenntnisse reden

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

Sind diese Sätze mit "Stufe" und "Niveau" zur Bezeichnung der Deutschkenntnisse richtig? Ich habe in allen bekannten Wörterbücher nachgeschaut, aber nichts gefunden.

> 1. Ich stehe/bin auf der Stufe/Niveau B1.
> 2. Welche Stufe/Niveau brauche ich für diese Stelle?
> 3. Diese Grammatik gehört zur/zum Unterstufe/Unterniveau.
> 4. Ich habe ein Zertifikat B1 Stufe/Niveau beim ÖSD.
> 5. Wenn ich auf die Oberstufe/Oberniveau gehe, kann ich diese Grammatik verstehen.

Comment: @hubert Shölnast Vielen Dank für Das Korrigieren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sätze 1 und 2 sind soweit richtig, nur dass unterschiedliche Artikel/Fragepronomen für das 'sächliche' Wort *Niveau* (Neutrum) fehlen (vgl. @userunknown):

> 1. Ich stehe/bin auf der Stufe/**dem** Niveau B1.

Alternative zu Satz 1: *Ich habe das Niveau/die Stufe B1 erreicht.*

> 2. Welche Stufe/**welches** Niveau brauche ich für diese Stelle?

Bei den anderen drei Sätzen sind mir noch andere Sachen aufgefallen:

> 3. Diese**r Teil der** Grammatik gehört zur (Unterstufe)/**unteren Stufe**/<s>Unterniveau</s> **zum unteren Niveau**.

Zu Satz 3: *Unterstufe* ist eigentlich ein Begriff aus der Schule und steht dort zumindest in Deutschland in der Regel für die Klassen 5--7.  In Bezug auf Sprachkenntnisse ergibt *Unterstufe/untere Stufe* nur Sinn, wenn man aktiv zwei oder drei konkrete Stufen (*Ober-*, [ggf. *Mittel-*] und *Unterstufe*) definiert.

*Unteres Niveau* ist korrekt, wenn man zwei (oder drei) Niveaus miteinander vergleicht (vs. *oberes* (oder *mittleres*) *Niveau*). Den Begriff *Unterniveau* gibt es in dem Zusammenhang jedoch nicht.

*Grammatik* bezeichnet alle Regeln einer Sprache, das heißt: genauer ist es, von einem *Teil der Grammatik* oder von einem *grammatikalischen Phänomen* zu sprechen.

> 4. Ich habe ein **ÖSD-Zertifikat der Stufe/des Niveaus B1** (*oder:* **für die Stufe/das Niveau B1**).

Bei Satz 4 muss die Wortstellung wie angegeben geändert werden.

> 5. Wenn ich...
>
> - <s>auf die Oberstufe/Oberniveau gehe</s>
> - **auf der oberen Stufe/auf dem oberen Niveau (angelangt) bin**
> - **das obere Niveau/die obere Stufe erreicht habe**
>
> ... kann ich diese**n Teil der** Grammatik verstehen.

Zu Satz 5: ***In** (!) die Oberstufe gehen* ist ebenfalls ein Begriff aus der Schule und bezeichnet zumindest in Deutschland den Besuch der letzten drei Klassen vor dem Abitur (in anderen Ländern *Matura* genannt).

Man kann jedoch *auf der oberen Stufe/dem oberen Niveau (angelangt) sein*. Der Ausdruck *irgendwo angelangt sein* bedeutet soviel wie *etwas erreicht haben*. *Eine Stufe/ein Niveau erreicht haben* geht auch.

Wie bei Satz 3 geht es außerdem genau genommen nur um einen *Teil der Grammatik*.

---

PS: statt *oberes/unteres* Niveau, welche eher **relativ** (vergleichend) sind, gibt es auch:

> - hohes/niedriges Niveau

..., was eher **absolut** verwendet wird.

Comment: Vielen Dank für ausführliche Erklärung. Es ist super

Answer (score 1):

Nein, es ist "die Stufe" (f) aber "das Nievau" (s).
Daher:

1. Ich stehe/bin auf der Stufe/dem Niveau B1.
2. Welche Stufe/welches Niveau brauche ich für diese Stelle?
3. Diese Grammatik gehört zur Unterstufe (kein Äquivalent mit Niveau, sonst hieße es aber "zum Unterniveau").
4. Ich habe ein Zertifikat **der/des** B1 Stufe/Niveaus beim ÖSD.
5. Wenn ich auf die Oberstufe gehe, kann ich diese Grammatik verstehen ("das Oberniveau" hier nicht möglich).

Obernstufe/Unterstufe sind feststehende Bezeichnungen, die nicht mit "Niveau" gebildet werden, auch wenn von der Bedeutung nichts dagegen spräche.